# .axml highlighting and intellisense not working in monodroid

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

I recently installed mono for Android and today I tried to get started.  In all of the tutorials I have seen, intellisense and highlighting both work in visual studio when editing .axml files, but after an install, uninstall, and re-install, mine still isn't working.  I guess I could go on like this, but it is just driving me absolutely nuts.

Comment: Still got the same problem and looking for an answer..if you already have solution please share..thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default VisualStudio editor for XML, then the intellisense should come from the namespace import: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

If you are using the Xamarin designer and its XML editor, however, then I don't believe that you will get any intellisense - that's a work in progress from the Xamarin team.

Comment: I have used <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" but still no intellisense support at all any idea about that